# loading dependecies fail for codeigniter4 shield on goDaddy

Tags: php, shared-hosting, codeigniter-4

I am setting up a site on goDaddy on codeigniter 4 using shield as an authentication platform.

the relevant configuration of the.env file

```
 app.baseURL = 'https://memorialcomalapa.org'
```

the codeigniter files are in the **public_html** folder

I have 2 modified .htaccess files, in the root of public_html and in the root of public_html/public

both only have one change with respect to what the codeigniter documentation says

```
RewriteBase /public/
```

I have also been careful that they end with a UNIX-style end of line.

This configuration works, but Shield imports a series of routes from the Auth.php configuration into Routes.php using the line:

```
service('auth')->routes($routes);
```

the routes are:

```
    public array $views = [
        'layout'                      => '\Layouts\main_metro',
        'login'                       => '\Shield\login',
        'register'                    => '\Shield\register',
        'action_email_2fa'            => '\Shield\email_2fa_show',
        'action_email_2fa_verify'     => '\Shield\email_2fa_verify',
        'action_email_2fa_email'      => '\Shield\Email\email_2fa_email',
        'action_email_activate_show'  => '\Shield\email_activate_show',
        'action_email_activate_email' => '\Shield\Email\email_activate_email',
        'magic-link-login'            => '\Shield\magic_link_form',
        'magic-link-message'          => '\Shield\magic_link_message',
        'magic-link-email'            => '\Shield\Email\magic_link_email',
    ];
```

For some reason none of those routes resolve well, I already tried with the login route and on a separate page I also tried to load '\Layouts\main_metro' using the standard view method

```
<?= $this->extend(config('Auth')->views['layout']) ?>
```

in both cases i got an error:

CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException
invalid file: \Shield\login.php

and

CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException
invalid file: \Layouts\main_metro

so please help!?